# Autowire a set of beans by type with name

Tags: spring, autowired

You can autowire all beans of type `Foo` by using:

```
@Autowired
private List<Foo> foos;
```

Spring will then look through the beans, find all which implement `Foo`, collect them in a list and inject them.

Is it possible to get the names of those beans as well? Something like:

```
@Autowired
private Map<String, Foo> foosByName;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

> [4.9.2 @Autowired](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation)
>   ...
>   Even typed Maps can be autowired as long as the expected key type is String. The Map values will contain all beans of the expected type, and the keys will contain the corresponding bean names